Topological Markov chains: how does this computation of 'entropy' work?
Everything I am saying is from Parry's paper 'Intrinsic Markov chains'. I try to summarise the ideas there for my own clarity before giving the question. We have an integer $s$ and the finite set $\mathcal{S} = \{0,\dots, s-1\}$.
Adjacency/Transition matrix: We have an $n\times n$ matrix $\sigma$ consisting of $0$'s and $1$'s. We assume that it is irreducible in the sense that, for any $i ,j \in \mathcal{S}$, there is an integer $n$ with $\sigma^n(i,j) >0$.
Perron-Frobenius eigenvectors: There is a real eigenvalue $\beta$ for $\sigma$ which is simple and which dominates in modulus all other eigenvalues. For $\beta$ there are corresponding left and right eigenvectors with all entries positive. We let $l$ and $h$ be the right and left eigenvectors corresponding to $\sigma$ normalized so that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i} l(i) = 1\ \text{ and }\ \sum_i l(i) h(i) = 1.
\end{equation}
Topological set of Markov chains $X$: In $\mathcal{S}^\mathbb{N}$, we define the compact subset
\begin{equation}
X := \left\lbrace x \in \mathcal{S}^\mathbb{N}: \forall n>0, \sigma(x_n,x_{n+1})=1 \right\rbrace.
\end{equation}
For $x \in X$ and $n>0$, we define the cylinder
\begin{equation}
C_n(x) := \left\lbrace y \in X : y_i = x_i \text{ for } i = 1,\dots, n\right\rbrace
\end{equation}
which we also write as  $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$.
Measure on $X$: We define the following Borel probability on $X$ (which we call $l$ by abuse of notation) via the formula
\begin{equation}
l(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \frac{l(x_n)}{\beta^{n-1}} \sigma(x_1, x_2)\cdots \sigma(x_{n-1}, x_n).
\end{equation}
Since $l$ is a right eigenvector for $\sigma$ this formula induces a probability on $\mathcal{S}^\mathbb{N}$ with support in $X$ via Kolmogorov's extension theorem. We now define the probability $p$ on $X$ by the fomula
\begin{equation}
p = \int h dl
\end{equation}
where, by abuse of notation, $h$ is the function which takes value $h(x_1,\dots, x_n) = h(x_1)$ on every cylinder in $X$. In particular we have for every cylinder,
\begin{equation}
p(x_1,\dots,x_n) = h(x_1) l(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \frac{h(x_1) \sigma(x_1, x_2) \cdots, \sigma(x_{n-1}, x_n) l(x_n)}{\beta^{n-1}}.
\end{equation}
Note, $l$ is not invariant under the shift map, but $p$ is.
The probability $p$ and its entropy: We define the entropy $H(p)$ as
\begin{equation}
H(p) := \lim_{n \to \infty} -\frac{1}{n} \sum_{\{C_n(x): x \in X\}} p(C_n(x)) \log p(C_n(x)).
\end{equation}
Question: How do I see that the entropy is given by $H(p) = \log \beta$?
Attempt: I compute, for $n >1$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{\{C_n(x): x \in \mathcal{S}^\mathbb{N}\}} p C_n(x) \log p C_n(x) &= \sum_{\{x_1, \dots, x_n \in \mathcal{S}\}}  \frac{h(x_1)\sigma(x_1,x_2) \cdots \sigma(x_{n-1}, x_n) l(x_n)}{\beta^{n-1}}  \log \frac{h(x_1)\sigma(x_1,x_2) \cdots \sigma(x_{n-1}, x_n) l(x_n)}{\beta^{n-1}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
What on earth am I supposed to do with this?
Thanks for your help.

Wait, maybe this is easy. I can sum over the intermediate indices to get
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{C_n(x)} p C_n(x) \log p C_n(x) &= \sum_{x_1} \sum_{x_n} \sigma^{n-1}(x_1,x_n)\frac{h(x_1) l(x_n)}{\beta^{n-1}} \log \frac{h(x_1) l(x_n)}{\beta^{n-1}} \\
&= \sum_{x_1} \sum_{x_n} \sigma^{n-1}(x_1, x_n) \frac{h(x_1) l(x_n)}{\beta^{n-1}} \left[\log \frac{h(x_1)}{\beta^{n-1}} + \log l(x_n)\right] \\
&= \sum_{x_1} \frac{h(x_1)}{\beta^{n-1}}\log \frac{h(x_1)}{\beta^{n-1}} \sum_{x_n} \sigma^{n-1} (x_1, x_n) l(x_n)\ \ +\ \ \sum_{x_n} \frac{l(x_n)}{\beta^{n-1}}\log l(x_n) \sum_{x_1} h(x_1)\sigma^{n-1}(x_1,x_n)    \\
&= \sum_{x_1} \frac{h(x_1)}{\beta^{n-1}} \log \left(\frac{h(x_1)}{\beta^{n-1}}\right) \beta^{n-1}l(x_1)  \ \ + \ \ \sum_{x_n}  \frac{l(x_n)}{\beta^{n-1}}\log(l(x_n)) h(x_n)\beta^{n-1} \\
&= \sum_{x_1} h(x_1) l(x_1) [\log h(x_1) - \log \beta^{n-1}] \ \ + \ \ \sum_{x_n} l(x_n)h(x_n) \log l(x_n).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Dividing by $-n$, using the normalization of $l$ and $h$, and taking the limit gives
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}  \log(\beta^{n-1}) = \log \beta.
\end{equation}
